# Modifying image in real time gtk

Tags: c, gtk, glib

I am making an app using GTK+3 and C in which there is an image. This image should be displayed for 5 minutes (for example). And during those 5 minutes, Black points should be randomly added to the image to make it **unclear**.
So I have two problems here:

1. The first one is how to insert real time in my program using GTK and C? I saw on the forum some topics in which they mentioned `g_timeout_add()` but I didn't quite understand how it works.. (and if this works)
2. The second problem is what functions should I use to add those black points on my image? and is it considered as image treatment?

Comment: g_timeout_add is a async timer that you can use its callback to perform some custom commands. Indeed this is what you need for adding every 5 minutes the dots. See documentation about it. Now, about the dots, see the documentation about GtkDrawingArea. Play around :)

Comment: ohhh okay! thanks! but is there a function for starting a process when i click play and ends it after many minutes ? (like a song for example?) or is it also g_timeout_add?

Comment: .. I meant to make it last for 5 minutes for example:
Button play pressed => process begins.
When 5 minutes have passed => process stopped!
@Joel

Comment: And how often should the picture be modified in that 5 minutes? Every few milliseconds or so?

Comment: @iMadz, yes...you can call g_timeout_add from a button clicked event, and you can stop it from the inner callback of g_timeout_add or destroy the id handle returned by g_timeout_add

Comment: @andlabs probably every second a white pixel should be added to the image. After 5 minutes, the image will be covered by pixels and won't clear anymore! this is what I'm looking forward to do! Sorry for the late answer!

Comment: @Joel oh okay thanks.. I will try this. But what i didn't quite understand is how to stop it from the inner callback of g_timeout_add?

Comment: @iMadz, all is in the documents, just read them

Comment: @iMadz the other half of the problem, after what Joel said (which combines to form your solution), is `gtk_widget_queue_draw()` to signal that the GtkDrawingArea needs updating after you modify the image.

Comment: @Joel okay i will thanks! the problem is that I'm new to gtk and i have a deadline to deliver the project in my high school